# Conda: First time using Conda-Forge. Is massive update normal?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

I am trying to install a package that is on conda-forge, the first time I've done this.  I'm doing this in a virtual-env, that's been working well and has a bunch of stuff in it (aka, not empty!)
When I go to install this package, it tries to update *everything*.  I'm worried I'm going to break my v-env...

Is this normal?

```
(f-env) PS C:\> conda config
(f-env) PS C:\> conda config --add channels conda-forge
(f-env) PS C:\> conda config --set channel_priority strict
(f-env) PS C:\> conda install spyder-notebook=0.4.0
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs\f-env

  added / updated specs:
    - spyder-notebook=0.4.0


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    alabaster-0.7.12           |             py_0          15 KB  conda-forge
    anyio-3.6.1                |     pyhd8ed1ab_1          83 KB  conda-forge
    argon2-cffi-21.3.0         |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          15 KB  conda-forge
    argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0|   py38h294d835_2          35 KB  conda-forge
    arrow-1.2.3                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          92 KB  conda-forge
    astroid-2.12.10            |   py38haa244fe_0         377 KB  conda-forge
    atomicwrites-1.4.1         |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          12 KB  conda-forge
    attrs-22.1.0               |     pyh71513ae_1          48 KB  conda-forge
    autopep8-1.6.0             |     pyhd8ed1ab_1          41 KB  conda-forge
    babel-2.10.3               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         6.7 MB  conda-forge
    backcall-0.2.0             |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          13 KB  conda-forge
    backports-1.0              |             py_2           4 KB  conda-forge
    backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.4|     pyhd8ed1ab_0           9 KB  conda-forge
    bcrypt-3.2.2               |   py38h294d835_0          41 KB  conda-forge
    beautifulsoup4-4.11.1      |     pyha770c72_0          96 KB  conda-forge
    bidict-0.22.0              |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          31 KB  conda-forge
    binaryornot-0.4.4          |             py_1         370 KB  conda-forge
    black-22.8.0               |   py38haa244fe_0         313 KB  conda-forge
    bleach-5.0.1               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         124 KB  conda-forge
    brotlipy-0.7.0             |py38h294d835_1004         329 KB  conda-forge
    bzip2-1.0.8                |       h8ffe710_4         149 KB  conda-forge
    ca-certificates-2022.9.14  |       h5b45459_0         189 KB  conda-forge
    certifi-2022.9.14          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         156 KB  conda-forge
    cffi-1.15.1                |   py38hd8c33c5_0         223 KB  conda-forge
    chardet-5.0.0              |   py38haa244fe_0         246 KB  conda-forge
    charset-normalizer-2.1.1   |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          36 KB  conda-forge
    click-8.1.3                |   py38haa244fe_0         146 KB  conda-forge
    cloudpickle-2.2.0          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          25 KB  conda-forge
    colorama-0.4.5             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          18 KB  conda-forge
    cookiecutter-2.1.1         |     pyh6c4a22f_0          90 KB  conda-forge
    cryptography-37.0.4        |   py38hb7941b4_0         1.1 MB  conda-forge
    debugpy-1.6.3              |   py38h885f38d_0         3.2 MB  conda-forge
    decorator-5.1.1            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          12 KB  conda-forge
    defusedxml-0.7.1           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          23 KB  conda-forge
    diff-match-patch-20200713  |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          38 KB  conda-forge
    dill-0.3.5.1               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          71 KB  conda-forge
    docutils-0.19              |   py38haa244fe_0         798 KB  conda-forge
    entrypoints-0.4            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0           9 KB  conda-forge
    flake8-4.0.1               |     pyhd8ed1ab_2          83 KB  conda-forge
    flit-core-3.7.1            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          44 KB  conda-forge
    gettext-0.19.8.1           |    ha2e2712_1008         4.9 MB  conda-forge
    glib-2.72.1                |       h7755175_0         460 KB  conda-forge
    glib-tools-2.72.1          |       h7755175_0         167 KB  conda-forge
    gst-plugins-base-1.20.3    |       h001b923_2         2.4 MB  conda-forge
    gstreamer-1.20.3           |       h6b5321d_2         2.2 MB  conda-forge
    icu-70.1                   |       h0e60522_0        17.0 MB  conda-forge
    idna-3.4                   |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          55 KB  conda-forge
    imagesize-1.4.1            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          10 KB  conda-forge
    importlib-metadata-4.11.4  |   py38haa244fe_0          33 KB  conda-forge
    importlib_metadata-4.11.4  |       hd8ed1ab_0           4 KB  conda-forge
    importlib_resources-5.9.0  |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          28 KB  conda-forge
    inflection-0.5.1           |     pyh9f0ad1d_0           9 KB  conda-forge
    intervaltree-3.0.2         |             py_0          23 KB  conda-forge
    ipykernel-6.15.3           |     pyh025b116_0         100 KB  conda-forge
    ipython-7.33.0             |   py38haa244fe_0         1.2 MB  conda-forge
    ipython_genutils-0.2.0     |             py_1          21 KB  conda-forge
    isort-5.10.1               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          79 KB  conda-forge
    jaraco.classes-3.2.2       |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          10 KB  conda-forge
    jedi-0.18.1                |     pyhd8ed1ab_2         799 KB  conda-forge
    jellyfish-0.9.0            |   py38h294d835_1          40 KB  conda-forge
    jinja2-3.1.2               |     pyhd8ed1ab_1          99 KB  conda-forge
    jinja2-time-0.2.0          |     pyhd8ed1ab_3           9 KB  conda-forge
    jpeg-9e                    |       h8ffe710_2         366 KB  conda-forge
    json5-0.9.5                |     pyh9f0ad1d_0          20 KB  conda-forge
    jsonschema-4.16.0          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          65 KB  conda-forge
    jupyter_client-7.3.5       |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          91 KB  conda-forge
    jupyter_core-4.11.1        |   py38haa244fe_0         106 KB  conda-forge
    jupyter_server-1.18.1      |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         232 KB  conda-forge
    jupyterlab-3.4.7           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         5.9 MB  conda-forge
    jupyterlab_pygments-0.2.2  |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          17 KB  conda-forge
    jupyterlab_server-2.15.1   |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          49 KB  conda-forge
    keyring-23.9.3             |   py38haa244fe_0          72 KB  conda-forge
    krb5-1.19.3                |       h1176d77_0         847 KB  conda-forge
    lazy-object-proxy-1.7.1    |   py38h294d835_1          33 KB  conda-forge
    libclang-14.0.6            |default_h77d9078_0         144 KB  conda-forge
    libclang13-14.0.6          |default_h77d9078_0        24.5 MB  conda-forge
    libffi-3.4.2               |       h8ffe710_5          41 KB  conda-forge
    libglib-2.72.1             |       h3be07f2_0         3.1 MB  conda-forge
    libiconv-1.16              |       he774522_0         680 KB  conda-forge
    libogg-1.3.4               |       h8ffe710_1          34 KB  conda-forge
    libpng-1.6.38              |       h19919ed_0         773 KB  conda-forge
    libsodium-1.0.18           |       h8d14728_1         697 KB  conda-forge
    libspatialindex-1.9.3      |       h39d44d4_4         437 KB  conda-forge
    libsqlite-3.39.3           |       hcfcfb64_0         642 KB  conda-forge
    libvorbis-1.3.7            |       h0e60522_0         267 KB  conda-forge
    libwebp-1.2.4              |       h8ffe710_0          76 KB  conda-forge
    libwebp-base-1.2.4         |       h8ffe710_0         328 KB  conda-forge
    libxml2-2.9.14             |       hf5bbc77_4         3.4 MB  conda-forge
    libxslt-1.1.35             |       h34f844d_0         500 KB  conda-forge
    libzlib-1.2.12             |       hcfcfb64_3          71 KB  conda-forge
    line_profiler-3.4.0        |   py38hd614ea7_1          79 KB  conda-forge
    lxml-4.9.1                 |   py38h294d835_0         1.1 MB  conda-forge
    lz4-c-1.9.3                |       h8ffe710_1         135 KB  conda-forge
    markupsafe-2.1.1           |   py38h294d835_1          25 KB  conda-forge
    matplotlib-inline-0.1.6    |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          12 KB  conda-forge
    mccabe-0.6.1               |             py_1           8 KB  conda-forge
    mistune-2.0.4              |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          67 KB  conda-forge
    more-itertools-8.14.0      |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          45 KB  conda-forge
    mypy_extensions-0.4.3      |   py38haa244fe_5          11 KB  conda-forge
    nbclassic-0.4.3            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         7.5 MB  conda-forge
    nbclient-0.6.8             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          65 KB  conda-forge
    nbconvert-7.0.0            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0           6 KB  conda-forge
    nbconvert-core-7.0.0       |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         189 KB  conda-forge
    nbconvert-pandoc-7.0.0     |     pyhd8ed1ab_0           5 KB  conda-forge
    nbformat-5.6.0             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         106 KB  conda-forge
    nest-asyncio-1.5.5         |     pyhd8ed1ab_0           9 KB  conda-forge
    notebook-6.4.12            |     pyha770c72_0         6.3 MB  conda-forge
    notebook-shim-0.1.0        |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          15 KB  conda-forge
    numpydoc-1.4.0             |     pyhd8ed1ab_1          45 KB  conda-forge
    openssl-1.1.1q             |       h8ffe710_0         5.8 MB  conda-forge
    packaging-21.3             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          36 KB  conda-forge
    pandoc-2.19.2              |       h57928b3_0        18.9 MB  conda-forge
    pandocfilters-1.5.0        |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          11 KB  conda-forge
    paramiko-2.11.0            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         140 KB  conda-forge
    parso-0.8.3                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          69 KB  conda-forge
    pathspec-0.10.1            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          35 KB  conda-forge
    pcre-8.45                  |       h0e60522_0         518 KB  conda-forge
    pexpect-4.8.0              |     pyh9f0ad1d_2          47 KB  conda-forge
    pickleshare-0.7.5          |          py_1003           9 KB  conda-forge
    pip-22.2.2                 |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         1.5 MB  conda-forge
    pkgutil-resolve-name-1.3.10|     pyhd8ed1ab_0           9 KB  conda-forge
    platformdirs-2.5.2         |     pyhd8ed1ab_1          16 KB  conda-forge
    pluggy-1.0.0               |   py38haa244fe_3          26 KB  conda-forge
    ply-3.11                   |             py_1          44 KB  conda-forge
    poyo-0.5.0                 |             py_0          14 KB  conda-forge
    prometheus_client-0.14.1   |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          49 KB  conda-forge
    prompt-toolkit-3.0.31      |     pyha770c72_0         254 KB  conda-forge
    psutil-5.9.2               |   py38h91455d4_0         367 KB  conda-forge
    ptyprocess-0.7.0           |     pyhd3deb0d_0          16 KB  conda-forge
    pycodestyle-2.8.0          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          39 KB  conda-forge
    pycparser-2.21             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         100 KB  conda-forge
    pydocstyle-6.1.1           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          34 KB  conda-forge
    pyflakes-2.4.0             |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          58 KB  conda-forge
    pygments-2.13.0            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         821 KB  conda-forge
    pylint-2.15.3              |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         325 KB  conda-forge
    pyls-spyder-0.4.0          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          10 KB  conda-forge
    pymongo-4.2.0              |   py38h885f38d_1         1.4 MB  conda-forge
    pynacl-1.5.0               |   py38h31c79cd_1         1.5 MB  conda-forge
    pyopenssl-22.0.0           |     pyhd8ed1ab_1         120 KB  conda-forge
    pyparsing-3.0.9            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          79 KB  conda-forge
    pyqt-5.15.7                |   py38h75e37d8_0         4.7 MB  conda-forge
    pyqt5-sip-12.11.0          |   py38h885f38d_0          82 KB  conda-forge
    pyqtwebengine-5.15.7       |   py38h75e37d8_0         139 KB  conda-forge
    pyrsistent-0.18.1          |   py38h294d835_1          85 KB  conda-forge
    pysocks-1.7.1              |     pyh0701188_6          19 KB  conda-forge
    python-3.8.13              |h9a09f29_0_cpython        16.9 MB  conda-forge
    python-dateutil-2.8.2      |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         240 KB  conda-forge
    python-fastjsonschema-2.16.2|     pyhd8ed1ab_0         242 KB  conda-forge
    python-lsp-black-1.2.1     |     pyhd8ed1ab_0           9 KB  conda-forge
    python-lsp-jsonrpc-1.0.0   |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          11 KB  conda-forge
    python-lsp-server-1.5.0    |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          46 KB  conda-forge
    python-slugify-6.1.2       |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          15 KB  conda-forge
    python_abi-3.8             |           2_cp38           4 KB  conda-forge
    pytoolconfig-1.2.2         |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          18 KB  conda-forge
    pytz-2022.2.1              |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         224 KB  conda-forge
    pywin32-303                |   py38h294d835_0         6.9 MB  conda-forge
    pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0       |py38haa244fe_1005          39 KB  conda-forge
    pywinpty-2.0.8             |   py38hd3f51b4_0         234 KB  conda-forge
    pyyaml-6.0                 |   py38h294d835_4         154 KB  conda-forge
    pyzmq-24.0.1               |   py38ha85f68a_0         461 KB  conda-forge
    qdarkstyle-3.0.3           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         313 KB  conda-forge
    qstylizer-0.2.2            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          17 KB  conda-forge
    qt-main-5.15.6             |       hf0cf448_0        68.8 MB  conda-forge
    qt-webengine-5.15.4        |       h7325c83_3        60.1 MB  conda-forge
    qtawesome-1.1.1            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         2.1 MB  conda-forge
    qtconsole-5.3.2            |     pyhd8ed1ab_0           6 KB  conda-forge
    qtconsole-base-5.3.2       |     pyha770c72_0          91 KB  conda-forge
    qtpy-2.2.0                 |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          48 KB  conda-forge
    qtwebkit-5.212             |       h0db62b3_6        12.5 MB  conda-forge
    requests-2.28.1            |     pyhd8ed1ab_1          53 KB  conda-forge
    rope-1.3.0                 |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         132 KB  conda-forge
    rtree-1.0.0                |   py38h8b54edf_1          49 KB  conda-forge
    send2trash-1.8.0           |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          17 KB  conda-forge
    setuptools-65.3.0          |     pyhd8ed1ab_1         782 KB  conda-forge
    sip-6.6.2                  |   py38h885f38d_0         519 KB  conda-forge
    six-1.16.0                 |     pyh6c4a22f_0          14 KB  conda-forge
    sniffio-1.3.0              |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          14 KB  conda-forge
    snowballstemmer-2.2.0      |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          57 KB  conda-forge
    ...
    ...
    whatthepatch-1.0.2         |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          15 KB  conda-forge
    wheel-0.37.1               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          31 KB  conda-forge
    win_inet_pton-1.1.0        |   py38haa244fe_4           9 KB  conda-forge
    wincertstore-0.2           |py38haa244fe_1008          15 KB  conda-forge
    winpty-0.4.3               |                4         1.1 MB  conda-forge
    wrapt-1.14.1               |   py38h294d835_0          49 KB  conda-forge
    xz-5.2.6                   |       h8d14728_0         213 KB  conda-forge
    yaml-0.2.5                 |       h8ffe710_2          62 KB  conda-forge
    yapf-0.32.0                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         129 KB  conda-forge
    zeromq-4.3.4               |       h0e60522_1         8.9 MB  conda-forge
    zipp-3.8.1                 |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          13 KB  conda-forge
    zlib-1.2.12                |       hcfcfb64_3         116 KB  conda-forge
    zstd-1.5.2                 |       h7755175_4         401 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       347.0 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  backports          conda-forge/noarch::backports-1.0-py_2
  backports.functoo~ conda-forge/noarch::backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  bzip2              conda-forge/win-64::bzip2-1.0.8-h8ffe710_4
  flit-core          conda-forge/noarch::flit-core-3.7.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  gettext            conda-forge/win-64::gettext-0.19.8.1-ha2e2712_1008
  glib-tools         conda-forge/win-64::glib-tools-2.72.1-h7755175_0
  jaraco.classes     conda-forge/noarch::jaraco.classes-3.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  krb5               conda-forge/win-64::krb5-1.19.3-h1176d77_0
  libclang13         conda-forge/win-64::libclang13-14.0.6-default_h77d9078_0
  libglib            conda-forge/win-64::libglib-2.72.1-h3be07f2_0
  libsqlite          conda-forge/win-64::libsqlite-3.39.3-hcfcfb64_0
  libwebp-base       conda-forge/win-64::libwebp-base-1.2.4-h8ffe710_0
  libzlib            conda-forge/win-64::libzlib-1.2.12-hcfcfb64_3
  lxml               conda-forge/win-64::lxml-4.9.1-py38h294d835_0
  more-itertools     conda-forge/noarch::more-itertools-8.14.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  nbconvert-core     conda-forge/noarch::nbconvert-core-7.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  nbconvert-pandoc   conda-forge/noarch::nbconvert-pandoc-7.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  notebook-shim      conda-forge/noarch::notebook-shim-0.1.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pandoc             conda-forge/win-64::pandoc-2.19.2-h57928b3_0
  pkgutil-resolve-n~ conda-forge/noarch::pkgutil-resolve-name-1.3.10-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  python_abi         conda-forge/win-64::python_abi-3.8-2_cp38
  pytoolconfig       conda-forge/noarch::pytoolconfig-1.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  qtconsole-base     conda-forge/noarch::qtconsole-base-5.3.2-pyha770c72_0
  tinycss2           conda-forge/noarch::tinycss2-1.1.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  tk                 conda-forge/win-64::tk-8.6.12-h8ffe710_0
  typing             conda-forge/noarch::typing-3.10.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  ucrt               conda-forge/win-64::ucrt-10.0.20348.0-h57928b3_0
  xz                 conda-forge/win-64::xz-5.2.6-h8d14728_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  anyio              pkgs/main/win-64::anyio-3.5.0-py38haa~ --> conda-forge/noarch::anyio-3.6.1-pyhd8ed1ab_1
  argon2-cffi-bindi~ pkgs/main::argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.~ --> conda-forge::argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0-py38h294d835_2
  arrow                 pkgs/main::arrow-1.2.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::arrow-1.2.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  astroid            pkgs/main::astroid-2.11.7-py38haa9553~ --> conda-forge::astroid-2.12.10-py38haa244fe_0
  atomicwrites           pkgs/main::atomicwrites-1.4.0-py_0 --> conda-forge::atomicwrites-1.4.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  attrs                pkgs/main::attrs-21.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::attrs-22.1.0-pyh71513ae_1
  babel                 pkgs/main::babel-2.9.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::babel-2.10.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  bcrypt             pkgs/main::bcrypt-3.2.0-py38h2bbff1b_1 --> conda-forge::bcrypt-3.2.2-py38h294d835_0
  bidict              pkgs/main::bidict-0.21.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::bidict-0.22.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  black              pkgs/main::black-22.6.0-py38haa95532_0 --> conda-forge::black-22.8.0-py38haa244fe_0
  bleach               pkgs/main::bleach-4.1.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::bleach-5.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  brotlipy           pkgs/main::brotlipy-0.7.0-py38h2bbff1~ --> conda-forge::brotlipy-0.7.0-py38h294d835_1004
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2022.07.19~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2022.9.14-h5b45459_0
  chardet            pkgs/main::chardet-4.0.0-py38haa95532~ --> conda-forge::chardet-5.0.0-py38haa244fe_0
  charset-normalizer pkgs/main::charset-normalizer-2.0.4-p~ --> conda-forge::charset-normalizer-2.1.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  click               pkgs/main::click-8.0.4-py38haa95532_0 --> conda-forge::click-8.1.3-py38haa244fe_0
  cloudpickle        pkgs/main::cloudpickle-2.0.0-pyhd3eb1~ --> conda-forge::cloudpickle-2.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  cookiecutter       pkgs/main::cookiecutter-1.7.3-pyhd3eb~ --> conda-forge::cookiecutter-2.1.1-pyh6c4a22f_0
  cryptography       pkgs/main::cryptography-37.0.1-py38h2~ --> conda-forge::cryptography-37.0.4-py38hb7941b4_0
  debugpy            pkgs/main::debugpy-1.5.1-py38hd77b12b~ --> conda-forge::debugpy-1.6.3-py38h885f38d_0
  dill                   pkgs/main::dill-0.3.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::dill-0.3.5.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  docutils           pkgs/main::docutils-0.18.1-py38haa955~ --> conda-forge::docutils-0.19-py38haa244fe_0
  flake8               pkgs/main::flake8-4.0.1-pyhd3eb1b0_1 --> conda-forge::flake8-4.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_2
  glib                    pkgs/main::glib-2.69.1-h5dc1a3c_1 --> conda-forge::glib-2.72.1-h7755175_0
  gst-plugins-base   pkgs/main::gst-plugins-base-1.18.5-h9~ --> conda-forge::gst-plugins-base-1.20.3-h001b923_2
  gstreamer          pkgs/main::gstreamer-1.18.5-hd78058f_0 --> conda-forge::gstreamer-1.20.3-h6b5321d_2
  icu                        pkgs/main::icu-58.2-ha925a31_3 --> conda-forge::icu-70.1-h0e60522_0
  idna                     pkgs/main::idna-3.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::idna-3.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  importlib-metadata pkgs/main::importlib-metadata-4.11.3-~ --> conda-forge::importlib-metadata-4.11.4-py38haa244fe_0
  importlib_metadata pkgs/main::importlib_metadata-4.11.3-~ --> conda-forge::importlib_metadata-4.11.4-hd8ed1ab_0
  importlib_resourc~ pkgs/main::importlib_resources-5.2.0-~ --> conda-forge::importlib_resources-5.9.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  ipykernel          pkgs/main/win-64::ipykernel-6.15.2-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::ipykernel-6.15.3-pyh025b116_0
  ipython            pkgs/main::ipython-7.31.1-py38haa9553~ --> conda-forge::ipython-7.33.0-py38haa244fe_0
  isort                 pkgs/main::isort-5.9.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::isort-5.10.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  jedi               pkgs/main/win-64::jedi-0.18.1-py38haa~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jedi-0.18.1-pyhd8ed1ab_2
  jellyfish          pkgs/main::jellyfish-0.9.0-py38h2bbff~ --> conda-forge::jellyfish-0.9.0-py38h294d835_1
  jinja2               pkgs/main::jinja2-3.0.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::jinja2-3.1.2-pyhd8ed1ab_1
  jpeg                        pkgs/main::jpeg-9e-h2bbff1b_0 --> conda-forge::jpeg-9e-h8ffe710_2
  jsonschema         pkgs/main/win-64::jsonschema-4.4.0-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jsonschema-4.16.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  jupyter_core       pkgs/main::jupyter_core-4.10.0-py38ha~ --> conda-forge::jupyter_core-4.11.1-py38haa244fe_0
  jupyterlab         pkgs/main/win-64::jupyterlab-3.4.4-py~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jupyterlab-3.4.7-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  jupyterlab_pygmen~ pkgs/main::jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-~ --> conda-forge::jupyterlab_pygments-0.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  jupyterlab_server  pkgs/main/win-64::jupyterlab_server-2~ --> conda-forge/noarch::jupyterlab_server-2.15.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  keyring            pkgs/main::keyring-23.4.0-py38haa9553~ --> conda-forge::keyring-23.9.3-py38haa244fe_0
  lazy-object-proxy  pkgs/main::lazy-object-proxy-1.6.0-py~ --> conda-forge::lazy-object-proxy-1.7.1-py38h294d835_1
  libclang           pkgs/main::libclang-12.0.0-default_h6~ --> conda-forge::libclang-14.0.6-default_h77d9078_0
  libffi                 pkgs/main::libffi-3.4.2-hd77b12b_4 --> conda-forge::libffi-3.4.2-h8ffe710_5
  libpng                pkgs/main::libpng-1.6.37-h2a8f88b_0 --> conda-forge::libpng-1.6.38-h19919ed_0
  libsodium          pkgs/main::libsodium-1.0.18-h62dcd97_0 --> conda-forge::libsodium-1.0.18-h8d14728_1
  libspatialindex    pkgs/main::libspatialindex-1.9.3-h6c2~ --> conda-forge::libspatialindex-1.9.3-h39d44d4_4
  libwebp               pkgs/main::libwebp-1.2.2-h2bbff1b_0 --> conda-forge::libwebp-1.2.4-h8ffe710_0
  libxml2              pkgs/main::libxml2-2.9.14-h0ad7f3c_0 --> conda-forge::libxml2-2.9.14-hf5bbc77_4
  line_profiler      pkgs/main::line_profiler-3.3.1-py38h5~ --> conda-forge::line_profiler-3.4.0-py38hd614ea7_1
  markupsafe         pkgs/main::markupsafe-2.1.1-py38h2bbf~ --> conda-forge::markupsafe-2.1.1-py38h294d835_1
  mistune            pkgs/main/win-64::mistune-0.8.4-py38h~ --> conda-forge/noarch::mistune-2.0.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  mypy_extensions    pkgs/main::mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py38~ --> conda-forge::mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py38haa244fe_5
  nbclassic          pkgs/main::nbclassic-0.3.5-pyhd3eb1b0~ --> conda-forge::nbclassic-0.4.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  nbclient           pkgs/main/win-64::nbclient-0.5.13-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::nbclient-0.6.8-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  nbconvert          pkgs/main/win-64::nbconvert-6.4.4-py3~ --> conda-forge/noarch::nbconvert-7.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  nbformat           pkgs/main/win-64::nbformat-5.5.0-py38~ --> conda-forge/noarch::nbformat-5.6.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  numpydoc           pkgs/main/win-64::numpydoc-1.4.0-py38~ --> conda-forge/noarch::numpydoc-1.4.0-pyhd8ed1ab_1
  paramiko           pkgs/main::paramiko-2.8.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0 --> conda-forge::paramiko-2.11.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pathspec           pkgs/main/win-64::pathspec-0.9.0-py38~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pathspec-0.10.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-22.1.2-py38haa9~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pip-22.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  platformdirs       pkgs/main/win-64::platformdirs-2.5.2-~ --> conda-forge/noarch::platformdirs-2.5.2-pyhd8ed1ab_1
  pluggy             pkgs/main::pluggy-1.0.0-py38haa95532_1 --> conda-forge::pluggy-1.0.0-py38haa244fe_3
  ply                     pkgs/main/win-64::ply-3.11-py38_0 --> conda-forge/noarch::ply-3.11-py_1
  prompt-toolkit     pkgs/main::prompt-toolkit-3.0.20-pyhd~ --> conda-forge::prompt-toolkit-3.0.31-pyha770c72_0
  psutil             pkgs/main::psutil-5.9.0-py38h2bbff1b_0 --> conda-forge::psutil-5.9.2-py38h91455d4_0
  pygments           pkgs/main::pygments-2.11.2-pyhd3eb1b0~ --> conda-forge::pygments-2.13.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pylint             pkgs/main/win-64::pylint-2.14.5-py38h~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pylint-2.15.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pymongo            pkgs/main::pymongo-3.12.0-py38hd77b12~ --> conda-forge::pymongo-4.2.0-py38h885f38d_1
  pynacl             pkgs/main::pynacl-1.5.0-py38h8cc25b3_0 --> conda-forge::pynacl-1.5.0-py38h31c79cd_1
  pyopenssl          pkgs/main::pyopenssl-22.0.0-pyhd3eb1b~ --> conda-forge::pyopenssl-22.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_1
  pyrsistent         pkgs/main::pyrsistent-0.18.0-py38h196~ --> conda-forge::pyrsistent-0.18.1-py38h294d835_1
  pysocks            pkgs/main/win-64::pysocks-1.7.1-py38h~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pysocks-1.7.1-pyh0701188_6
  python-slugify     pkgs/main::python-slugify-5.0.2-pyhd3~ --> conda-forge::python-slugify-6.1.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pytz               pkgs/main/win-64::pytz-2022.1-py38haa~ --> conda-forge/noarch::pytz-2022.2.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pywin32             pkgs/main::pywin32-302-py38h2bbff1b_2 --> conda-forge::pywin32-303-py38h294d835_0
  pywin32-ctypes     pkgs/main::pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0-py38_~ --> conda-forge::pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0-py38haa244fe_1005
  pywinpty           pkgs/main::pywinpty-2.0.2-py38h5da7b3~ --> conda-forge::pywinpty-2.0.8-py38hd3f51b4_0
```

....

Comment: The simple answer to your question is yes, depending on what you are installing.  BTW:  This site is not a discussion forum, it exists to answer secific technical questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a new channel in this fashion, you change the search priority for conda installations & updates. Conda will now prefer any package from `conda-forge` over packages available on `main`/`defaults`. So yes, large updates like this would be expected.

Alternatively, you can do one of the following:

1. Open your `~/.condarc` and switch the priority order so packages from `main`/`defaults` are prioritized over those in `conda-forge`, `conda-forge` will only be used as a fallback if the package is unavailable in `main`/`defaults`, e.g.:

   ```
   # ~/.condarc
   channels:
     - defaults
     - conda-forge
   ```
2. Remove the `conda-forge` channel from your `~/.condarc` and instead only specify it when installing a package that you need from `conda-forge`, e.g.:

   ```
   conda install conda-forge::spyder-notebook=0.4.0
   ```